# copy information to few DB in parallel with single read

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, thread-safety, parallels

Currently I have a code- that take any update on "Source DB" and copy it to "Destination DB"

I need to make it that with **single read call** from the "Source DB" **of the Update** and copy in parallel to few "Destination DB"

```
def loop(partial_src_db=None, partial_dst_db=None, collection_name=None, 
**options):

src_db = partial_src_db()

stream = None
while True:
try:

    collection_in = source_db.get_collection(collection_name)
    collection_out = destination_db.get_collection(collection_name)

    with collection_in.watch(full_document='updateLookup') as stream:

        for change in stream:
            oper_type = change['operationType']

            logger.debug(f"{oper_type} received: {collection_name}")

            if oper_type in ignored_ops:
                logger.debug(f"{oper_type} operation ignored")
                continue

            if oper_type == "insert":
                callback = db_insert_callback

            elif oper_type == "replace":
                # db_update_callback(change)
                callback = db_update_callback

            elif oper_type == "delete":
                callback = db_remove_callback

            callback(change, collection_out=collection_out)


except Exception as ex:
    logger.exception(ex)

finally:
    if stream:
        stream.close()
```

example to insert

```
def db_insert_callback(insert_change, collection_out):
doc = insert_change['fullDocument']
# logger.info(insert_change)
try:
    collection_out.insert(doc)
except Exception as ex:
    logger.exception(ex)
```

The main look like that

```
def main(**options):
partial_src_db = partial(db_connect, db_host=settings.SRC_RB_HOST, 
db_name=settings.SRC_RB_NAME,
                         db_user=settings.SRC_RB_USER, 
db_pass=settings.SRC_RB_PASS,
                         replica=settings.SRC_RB_REPLICA)
partial_dst_db = partial(db_connect, db_host=settings.DEST_RB_HOST, 
db_name=settings.DEST_RB_NAME)
src_db = partial_src_db()
src_db = partial_src_db()
logger.debug("connected to src db")
db_coll_names = src_db.list_collection_names()
cli_collection_names = options.get('collection') or db_coll_names
coll_names = list(set(db_coll_names) & set(cli_collection_names))
for coll_name in coll_names:                                                      
    partial_loop = partial(loop, partial_src_db=partial_dst_db, 
partial_dst_db=environment_list,
                           collection_name=coll_name, **options)
    t = Thread(target=partial_loop, daemon=False, name=coll_name)
    t.start()
```

hope someone will success help me , thank you

Comment: Are you saying that you need to do all the callbacks concurrently? This is not very clear.

Comment: this code is "listener" to updates of source DB , and when a update happen -> send update to another DB  .     
what i need : code that listener to updates , and when some update happen -> send update to FEW DB, concurrently ,

Comment: You're just repeating what you have already said and I am sorry that I don't understand what "send update to FEW DB" means" if it does not mean invoke the callback. This may be much clearer to everybody else.

Comment: do callbacks concurrently with threads where "collection_out" - it a list

Comment: @Booboo I realize i didn't post the "function name" and what it get,I update it now

Answer (score 1):

If `collections.out` is a `list` instance, then it is thread safe under add operations. However, it's not clear that if your `db_insert_callback` method is truly representative of your callbacks that anything will be gained by using multithreading or multiprocessing. This is because if most of what you are doing in the submitted job is just adding something to a list, which by definition must be a serialized operation, there can't be much concurrency/parallelization.

On the chance that there is more to the callback function then you have shown or for your edification purposes, this is how you would mutithread the callbacks:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

# example callback
def db_insert_callback(insert_change, collection_out):
    doc = insert_change['fullDocument']
    # logger.info(insert_change)
    try:
        collection_out.insert(doc)
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.exception(ex)


def loop(partial_src_db=None, partial_dst_db=None, collection_name=None, **options):

    src_db = partial_src_db()
    
    N_THREADS = 64 # depends on number of changes you expect in stream
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(workers=N_THREADS) as executor:
        while True:
            try:
                collection_in = source_db.get_collection(collection_name)
                collection_out = destination_db.get_collection(collection_name)
            
                with collection_in.watch(full_document='updateLookup') as stream:
            
                    futures = []
                    for change in stream:
                        oper_type = change['operationType']
            
                        logger.debug(f"{oper_type} received: {collection_name}")
            
                        if oper_type in ignored_ops:
                            logger.debug(f"{oper_type} operation ignored")
                            continue
            
                        if oper_type == "insert":
                            callback = db_insert_callback
            
                        elif oper_type == "replace":
                            # db_update_callback(change)
                            callback = db_update_callback
            
                        elif oper_type == "delete":
                            callback = db_remove_callback
            
                        futures.append(executor.submit(callback, change, collection_out=collection_out))
                        for future in futures:
                             # Wait for each job to complete.
                             # This may throw an exception if the callback threw an exception:
                            future.result()
            
            
            except Exception as ex:
                logger.exception(ex)
            
            finally:
                if stream:
                    stream.close()
```

**Note:** I don't know what class `stream` is, but the `with` statement that returns this value suggests that the context handler for this might be closing the stream automatically when the `with` block terminates. If that is the case, you can delete the assignment `stream = None` and the `finally` block.

**Update**

I have updated the source to enclose the code in function `loop` as you have provided (you really do need to get your indentation correct). However:

You define an argument, `partial_src_db`, whose default value is `None`, yet you call `partial_src_db()` without testing to see if it is `None`. Then you assign the return value to `src_db` and never reference this variable again. If `loop` is never going to be passed a `None` value for `partial_src_db`, then don't provide a default value of `None` for this argument.

Comment: yes exist 2 more callbacks  that i didnt put here 
" db_update_callback" and "db_remove_callback"

Comment: I know there are other callbacks. I mean whether the callbacks contain more operations other than a simple list insertion. If each callback is as simple as what you have shown, you will not gain much by multithreading.

Comment: 1)I realize i didn't post the "function name" and what it get,I update it now 
2) the callbacks pretty simple as it this one

Comment: and i added the Main

Answer (score 0):

Open both the DB at the same time and store the data of source DB in a variable.Then insert the value of the variable in the Destination DB

Comment: i would love to see it as code , cause theoretically i understand how to do it , but practically i dont know

Comment: I dont know much about Databases, just know a bit about mysql

Comment: i mean in python, imagine i make all the connection and open it (i have a code for that)

Comment: ok I can try to show it with two different text files. Or you can use threading to open two databases with each thread and then do the transfers

Comment: can you write code of how it will look ?

Answer (score 0):

Here the **source.txt** contains some data and **dest.txt** is the file where the data is written.
For text files it is done in this way:

```
f=open('source.txt','r')
g=open('dest.txt','w')

r=f.read()
r=r.split()
for x in r:
    g.write(x+' ')

f.close()
g.close()
```

So, for databases probably using threading connect to the databases with each thread and do the transfers in those thread.